# jqGrid data loading

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have 3 jqGrid instances on a page and all of them use the same grid data except it's filtered differently for each. I don't want to have to make a separate ajax call for each grid to load its data.

Is there a way for all 3 to work with the same data locally? I see the "loadonce" option but I don't think that's what I need, based on the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you make a single call using jQuery's [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method, then update the grids manually using the [addJSONData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) or [addRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) methods on jqGrid.